# Pandas fill in missing dates in DataFrame with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add missing dates for a specific date range, but keep all columns. I found many posts using `afreq()`, `resample()`, `reindex()`, but they seemed to be for Series and I couldn't get them to work for my DataFrame.

Given a sample dataframe:

```
data = [{'id' : '123', 'product' : 'apple', 'color' : 'red', 'qty' : 10, 'week' : '2019-3-7'}, {'id' : '123', 'product' : 'apple', 'color' : 'blue', 'qty' : 20, 'week' : '2019-3-21'}, {'id' : '123', 'product' : 'orange', 'color' : 'orange', 'qty' : 8, 'week' : '2019-3-21'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


    color   id product  qty       week
0     red  123   apple   10   2019-3-7
1    blue  123   apple   20  2019-3-21
2  orange  123  orange    8  2019-3-21
```

My goal is to return below; filling in qty as 0, but fill other columns. Of course, I have many other ids. I would like to be able to specify the start/end dates to fill; this example uses 3/7 to 3/21.

```
    color   id product  qty       week
0     red  123   apple   10   2019-3-7
1    blue  123   apple   20  2019-3-21
2  orange  123  orange    8  2019-3-21
3     red  123   apple    0  2019-3-14
4     red  123   apple    0  2019-3-21 
5    blue  123   apple    0   2019-3-7
6    blue  123   apple    0  2019-3-14
7  orange  123  orange    0   2019-3-7
8  orange  123  orange    0  2019-3-14
```

How can I keep the remainder of my DataFrame intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you case , you just need do with `unstack` and `stack` + `reindex`

```
df.week=pd.to_datetime(df.week)
s=pd.date_range(df.week.min(),df.week.max(),freq='7 D')

df=df.set_index(['color','id','product','week']).\
      qty.unstack().reindex(columns=s,fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
df

    color   id product    level_3     0
0    blue  123   apple 2019-03-14   0.0
1    blue  123   apple 2019-03-21  20.0
2  orange  123  orange 2019-03-14   0.0
3  orange  123  orange 2019-03-21   8.0
4     red  123   apple 2019-03-07  10.0
5     red  123   apple 2019-03-14   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to expose the implicitly missing rows; afterwards you can fill with `fillna`:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.week = pd.to_datetime(df.week)

# create new dates, which will be used to expand the dataframe
new_dates = {"week": pd.date_range(df.week.min(), df.week.max(), freq="7D")}

# use the complete function
# note how color, id and product are wrapped together 
# this ensures only missing values based on data in the dataframe is exposed
# if you want all combinations, then you get rid of the tuple,
(df
.complete(("color", "id", "product"), new_dates, sort = False)
.fillna({'qty':0, downcast='infer')
)

    id product   color  qty       week
0  123   apple     red   10 2019-03-07
1  123   apple    blue   20 2019-03-21
2  123  orange  orange    8 2019-03-21
3  123   apple     red    0 2019-03-14
4  123   apple     red    0 2019-03-21
5  123   apple    blue    0 2019-03-07
6  123   apple    blue    0 2019-03-14
7  123  orange  orange    0 2019-03-07
8  123  orange  orange    0 2019-03-14
```