# Pandas fill in missing monthly dates in DataFrame, fill up one specific column with zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing an issue with Pandas and how to fill up missing dates in a DataFrame.
The structure of the given DataFrame is as follows:

```
     Amount  Code     Type   Date
0     34.97  J36J     74343 2016-01-01
1     16.32  J36J     74343 2016-04-01
2     10.30  J36J     69927 2015-12-01
3     10.45  J36J     69927 2016-07-01
4      5.63  J36J     69927 2017-03-01
5     15.79  J36J     69927 2018-09-01
6     15.00  J36J     69927 2019-06-01
7      6.44  J36J     69926 2016-03-01
8      6.47  J36J     69926 2017-03-01
9     15.00  J36J     69926 2018-07-01
10    15.00  J36J     69926 2019-06-01
```

- Amount: well, the amount
- Code: Productcode which is the same throughout the entire DataFrame
- Type: A Producttype, there are many different ones
- Date: A Daterange which spans the time between December 2015 to
  September 2020.

My goal is to have a monthly entry for every Type covering this timespan.
Meaning, every Material should have 58 entries.
The 'artificially' created monthly entries should have an amount of 0.
So, my expected output would be (just for one Type, as an example)

```
     Amount  Code     Type   Date
0     34.97  J36J     74343 2016-01-01
1     16.32  J36J     74343 2016-02-01
2     0      J36J     74343 2016-03-01
3     0      J36J     74343 2016-04-01
4     0      J36J     74343 2016-05-01
5     0      J36J     74343 2016-06-01
6     0      J36J     74343 2016-07-01
7     0      J36J     74343 2016-08-01
8     0      J36J     74343 2016-09-01
9     0      J36J     74343 2016-10-01
10    0      J36J     74343 2016-11-01
11    0      J36J     74343 2016-12-01
```

Fortunately, somebody already had the same question
( [Pandas fill in missing dates in DataFrame with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035939/pandas-fill-in-missing-dates-in-dataframe-with-multiple-columns) )

I adapted the quite helpful answer to my case:

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
s=pd.date_range(df.Date.min(),df.Date.max(),freq='MS')

df=df.set_index(['Code','Type','Date']).\
      Amount.unstack().reindex(columns=s,fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
df
```

This worked quite well, but I checked the resulting DataFrame afterwards and it seems like some of the dates are missing.

```
398     74343  J36J 2016-01-01  34.97
399     74343  J36J 2016-02-01   0.00
400     74343  J36J 2016-04-01  16.32
401     74343  J36J 2016-05-01   0.00
402     74343  J36J 2016-06-01   0.00
403     74343  J36J 2016-08-01   0.00
404     74343  J36J 2016-10-01   0.00
405     74343  J36J 2016-11-01   0.00
406     74343  J36J 2016-12-01   0.00
```

Do any of you know what could be the reason for this?
I'm assuming maybe it's because of the Frequency ('MS') I've chosen? but I cannot think any of the others could be fitting.  (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) OR do I have to set the datarange manually?
In my initial DataFrame obviously not all Dates are available.

Any help on that matter is appreciated.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a subtle one, lots of fun.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Amount' :[34.97, 16.32, 10.3, 10.45, 5.63, 15.79, 15, 6.44, 6.47, 15, 15],
'Code': ['J36J','J36J','J36J','J36J','J36J','J36J','J36J','J36J','J36J','J36J','J36J'],
'Type': [74343,74343,69927,69927,9927,69927,69927,69926,69926,69926,69926],
'Date': ['1/1/2016','4/1/2016','12/1/2015','7/1/2016','3/1/2017','9/1/2018','6/1/2019','3/1/2016','3/1/2017','7/1/2018','6/1/2019']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df
```

this got the starting point of the values that were above.  Then working out what happened took a while,  the problem was we were using the same s for the whole of the types not individually.  So if a date was in another type it was not overwritten.

To solve this I did this in pieces so that we could build it back together.

```
outdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
s=pd.date_range(df.Date.min(),df.Date.max(),freq='MS')
for name, subdf in df.groupby('Type'):
    thisdf=subdf.set_index(['Code','Type','Date']).\
        Amount.unstack().reindex(columns=s,fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
    thisdf.rename(columns={0: "Amount", "level_2": "Date"}, errors="raise",inplace=True)
    thisdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
    thisdf = thisdf[['Code', 'Type', 'Date', 'Amount']]
    outdf = pd.concat([outdf,thisdf])
    outdf = outdf[['Code', 'Type', 'Date', 'Amount']]

outdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
outdf = outdf[['Code', 'Type', 'Date', 'Amount']]
```

So what we did is broke it into individual items then glued them back together after each time through the groupby.  Then we would have no missing dates from other types coming through on this type.

Comment: Wow, that was some next level Sherlock-work, thank you so much! 
That's why I like StackOverflow so much, you always learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to expose the implicitly missing rows; afterwards you can fill with `fillna`:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# create a dictionary of dates, spanning from December 2015 to September 2020
new_dates = {"Date": pd.date_range(start = "2015-12-01", end = "2020-09-01", freq="MS")}

# apply with `complete` for each group of `Type` and `Code`, 
# and fill the null values in `Amount` with 0:

df.complete(new_dates, by=["Type", "Code"], sort=True).fillna({'Amount': 0})

     Amount  Code   Type       Date
0       0.0  J36J   9927 2015-12-01
1       0.0  J36J   9927 2016-01-01
2       0.0  J36J   9927 2016-02-01
3       0.0  J36J   9927 2016-03-01
4       0.0  J36J   9927 2016-04-01
..      ...   ...    ...        ...
227     0.0  J36J  74343 2020-05-01
228     0.0  J36J  74343 2020-06-01
229     0.0  J36J  74343 2020-07-01
230     0.0  J36J  74343 2020-08-01
231     0.0  J36J  74343 2020-09-01

[232 rows x 4 columns]
```